# How much bandwidth do I need to buy from my ISP to upload 21.4MB of data consistently without experiencing severe downtimes

Tags: networking

My ISP provides me with 10mbps but my network is very slow at all times, I have done a speed test, both download and upload is 12.5MB. How much bandwidth should my ISP provide so that I may not experience downtimes and slow internet?

Comment: MB is a unit for **size**, bandwidth is a unit for **transfer *speed*** i.e.  `bytes` versus `bytes` (or bits) **`per second`**  - It makes quite  a difference if you need to upload a 21.4 MB file once a day,  or five 21.4 MB files every second...

Answer (score 1):

Consumer internet connections are usually oversubscribed with a fair use policy and no guaranties  to be able to offer them at competitive price levels.

To get **guaranteed  bandwidth** (regardless of how much bandwidth you need) you need a **business connection with a SLA** and generally speaking that will come at premium price point.

To get  less downtime businesses typically get an additional internet connection (often with a different Telco and ISP) for redundancy and failover.